# Do unique indexes also increase query efficiency in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I need to create a unique index on a field in mongoDB in order to prevent duplicates in my collection. I also want to create a single-field index on that same field in order to optimize for queries.

Do I need to create these two different indexes? Or will the unique index be used for queries as well?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What makes you think you need a second index on the same column? It doesn't begin to make sense.

Comment: It doesn't. Hence why I asked the question. I was unsure after reading this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350879/advantage-of-a-unique-index-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

The unique index will be used for queries, so the extra index is unnecessary.

You can test this, by looking at the indexes considered in the output from `explain` in the shell.